# Handle error with try in R

Tags: r, try-catch

I am trying to make function that returns geometric mean with data.
I want to make loop with try() to pass valid data, but what i tried actually didn't worked.

This is function

```
R=function(g)
{
k=1
n=length(g)
for(i in 1 : n) 
{ 
ifelse(g[i]>0, k<-k*g[i], stop("Negative component"))
k
}
t=k^(1/n)
t
}
```

And i want to use this function in this loop

```
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(rnorm(10000, mean=3), ncol=25, dimnames=list(NULL, paste("X",
1:25, sep=".")))


v=rep(0,400)
for(i in 1 : 400)
{  
try("v[i]=R(data[,i])",TRUE)
}
v
```

I want to get means for valid data, but it makes all value to 0

```
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 [73] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[109] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[145] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[181] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[217] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[253] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[289] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[325] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[361] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[397] 0 0 0 0
```

Can you let me know where was wrong??
Thanks

Comment: Your function always fails, e.g., `R(1)`, because `ifelse()` works by evaluating _both_ arguments. You want `if (g[i] > 0) k <- k * g[i] else stop("...")`, but really just avoid iteration `if (!all(g > 0)) stop("..."); exp(mean(log(g)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the missing declaration of `t` as a numeric vector and the syntax of `try()` function. The following code should work, it worked for me.

```
R=function(g)
{
 t = numeric(length(g))
 k=1
 n=length(g)
 for(i in 1 : n) 
 { 
   ifelse(g[i]>0, k<-k*g[i], stop("Negative component"))
 }
t=k^(1/n)
t
}
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(rnorm(10000, mean=3), ncol=25, dimnames=list(NULL,paste("X",
                                                                    1:25, sep=".")))

v=numeric(400)
for(i in 1 : 400)
{  
 try(v[i]<-R(data[i,]),TRUE)
}
v
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way i can put NA instead of 0.00000 as well?

Comment: try `v=c(rep(NA, 400))` instead of `v=numeric(400)` in the above answer